# How to configure adding a comment line before a query in JNDI

Tags: java, jndi

I have a got a very interesting requirement to add a comment string (like `/*Query Hint VPOD100*/`) before each query getting executed through JNDI. Is there any way we can modify query and comment (or query hint) before each query?

Please find the JNDI configuration which I am using in jboss-as-7.2.0.Final.

```
<datasource jndi-name="java:/avalon-ds" pool-name="avalon-ds" enabled="true" use-ccm="false">
    <connection-url>jdbc:teradata://env.corp.xyz.com/charset=UTF8,DBC_PORT=1025</connection-url>
    <driver-class>com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver</driver-class>
    <driver>TeradataDriver</driver>
    <new-connection-sql>select 1</new-connection-sql>
    <pool>
        <min-pool-size>2</min-pool-size>
        <max-pool-size>4</max-pool-size>
        <prefill>true</prefill>
        <use-strict-min>true</use-strict-min>
        <flush-strategy>IdleConnections</flush-strategy>
    </pool>
    <security>
        <user-name>user</user-name>
        <password>password</password>
    </security>
    <validation>
        <check-valid-connection-sql>select 1</check-valid-connection-sql>
        <validate-on-match>true</validate-on-match>
        <background-validation>true</background-validation>
        <background-validation-millis>3000</background-validation-millis>
    </validation>
    <timeout>
        <blocking-timeout-millis>60000</blocking-timeout-millis>
        <idle-timeout-minutes>5</idle-timeout-minutes>
    </timeout>
    <statement>
        <share-prepared-statements>false</share-prepared-statements>
    </statement>
</datasource>
```

Please let me know if there are any questions. Thank you going through my question.

Comment: AFAICT you can't configure this from the [`datasource`](http://www.ironjacamar.org/doc/userguide/1.1/en-US/html_single/index.html#deployingds) element. I can't see any option to do what you want.

Comment: thanks TT for your comments.

Comment: Perhaps if you conclude this can't be done from an option in the datasource element, you should rephrase your question + title?

Comment: I am working on this, will post the solution once I am done

Answer (score 0):

Instead of comments use **annotations**:

```
@Comment("Query Hint VPOD100")
... method
```

For enforcing then annotation processing is possible, or using reflection, or hooking in the validation.

Not exactly what you wanted, but even a bit more operational.

Comment: Hello Joop, thanks for your reply. there is another business logic behind adding these comment lines getting used in Database gateway and load-balancers. Challenge is to make configuration changes without touching the code-base to modify queries and add query hint.